# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, syntax-error

So. I am trying to write a simple extension to better understand JS(and extensions in general). I took info from google's FAQ but I get an error in line 4 (tabID?). Any tips?

```
var timetoupdate = 500 * 60;

chrome.tabs.reload(
  tabId?: number,
  reloadProperties?: object,
  callback?: function,
);

setTimeout(chrome.tabs.reload, timetoupdate);
```

This is from init.js that is loaded by manifest.json

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: But doesn't .js mean that it is JavaScript?

Comment: @NickIAm `.js` is just a file extension. You can place any text into that file. That doesn't make it valid JavaScript. Looks like you copied TypeScript code.

Comment: He means your code is not Javascript, it looks you just copy pasted the definition of `chrome.tabs.reload`, your not calling it.  IOW:  `tabID?: number`,  means you meant to put a number there,,.. eg.   `chrome.tabs.reload(1, {}, () =>{}`  etc.

Comment: Okay. So. Any hints?

Comment: What you've shown looks like a type definition from TypeScript, it's not valid JavaScript code for two different reasons (the `?` and the `function`), and you probably don't have in-scope identifiers `number` and `object` either, but that code is trying to use in-scope identifiers by those names.

Comment: I just searched for info on how to update the needed tab periodically and have found 
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: Hints? Depends on what you’re trying to do—are you trying to call `reload`? Do you want to pass any parameters? The docs show what the functions takes as parameters. You may want to take a step back—see how the examples at the top use the functions (like `create`) compared to how they’re documented?

Comment: @NickIAm - What it's showing you there (specifically [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-reload)) is a description of the object you have to provide, not an example. You have to provide an object with any combination of those three properties (since they're all optional -- the `?` tells us that). The values of the properties you do provide have to match the types shown. So `tabId` (if provided) must be a number, `reloadProperties` must be an object of some kind (there are probably specific properties it should have), and `callback` must be a function.

Comment: So I can have something like this instead?

var timetoupdate = 500 * 60;

function reloadTP()
{
 chrome.tabs.reload();
};

setTimeout(reloadTP(), timetoupdate);